# Display Grouped AND Individual labels in Excel Bar Chart

Tags: excel, charts

I'm trying to create a chart that contains the percentage of Paid Time Off (PTO) that people have used for the calendar year.  Each person is on a specific team, so I would like to group the bars per team, but still display everyone's name.  Is this possible?  I have 4 teams total.

Example Data:

> Employee Name     Employee Team    % PTO Take for Year
>   Person 1                 Team 1                             .2
>   Person 2                           Team 1                              .35
>   Person 3                              Team 1                              .6
>   Person 4                           Team 2                              .15
>   Person 5                           Team 2                              .3

The x-axis is 0% - 100% and the y-axis should be everyone's name, but grouped by team.  Something like this:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's two ways to achieve similar result. You have to prepare the data a bit differently, but it's quite easy to generate this kind of a chart then.

1. The first way is to separate the teams into different series by separating the team values into different columns. This automatically colours the different teams in a different colour:
   [image]
2. The second way uses multilevel categories to achieve a similar result. It's a bit easier to prepare the data based on your current data. But you would have to manually colour the teams with different colours:
   [image]

I used random to generate the data so chart don't have the same values. I also used reverse axis on both charts and added a blank line between the teams to separate them a bit more. Both are simple clustered bar chart (overlap to 100 and 0 gaps), but make sure that you select the whole range of data, as shown on the first picture or excel will plot only a part of the data.

Comment: Thanks so much Mitja, this worked perfect! I didn't know formatting the data made such a big difference.